# pandas dataframe: how to count the number of 1 rows in a binary column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"first_column": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

>>> df
    first_column
0              0
1              0
2              0
3              1
4              1
5              1
6              0
7              0
8              1
9              1
10             0
11             0
12             0
13             0
14             1
15             1
16             1
17             1
18             1
19             0
20             0
```

`first_column` is a binary column of 0s and 1s. There are "clusters" of consecutive ones, which are always found in pairs of at least two.

My goal is to create a column which "counts" the number of rows of ones per group:

```
>>> df
    first_column    counts
0              0        0
1              0        0
2              0        0
3              1        3
4              1        3
5              1        3
6              0        0
7              0        0
8              1        2
9              1        2
10             0        0
11             0        0
12             0        0
13             0        0
14             1        5
15             1        5
16             1        5
17             1        5
18             1        5
19             0        0
20             0        0
```

This sounds like a job for `df.loc()`, e.g. `df.loc[df.first_column == 1]`...something

I'm just not sure how to take into account each individual "cluster" of ones, and how to label each of the unique clusters with the "row count".

How would one do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach with NumPy's [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [`bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
def cumsum_bincount(a):  
    # Append 0 & look for a [0,1] pattern. Form a binned array based off 1s groups
    ids = a*(np.diff(np.r_[0,a])==1).cumsum()

    # Get the bincount, index into the count with ids and finally mask out 0s
    return a*np.bincount(ids)[ids]
```

Sample run -

```
In [88]: df['counts'] = cumsum_bincount(df.first_column.values)

In [89]: df
Out[89]: 
    first_column  counts
0              0       0
1              0       0
2              0       0
3              1       3
4              1       3
5              1       3
6              0       0
7              0       0
8              1       2
9              1       2
10             0       0
11             0       0
12             0       0
13             0       0
14             1       5
15             1       5
16             1       5
17             1       5
18             1       5
19             0       0
20             0       0
```

Set the first `6` elems to be `1s` and then test out -

```
In [101]: df.first_column.values[:5] = 1

In [102]: df['counts'] = cumsum_bincount(df.first_column.values)

In [103]: df
Out[103]: 
    first_column  counts
0              1       6
1              1       6
2              1       6
3              1       6
4              1       6
5              1       6
6              0       0
7              0       0
8              1       2
9              1       2
10             0       0
11             0       0
12             0       0
13             0       0
14             1       5
15             1       5
16             1       5
17             1       5
18             1       5
19             0       0
20             0       0
```

Comment: This works exceptionally well! I appreciate the comments explaining what is going on as well

Answer (score 5):

- Since `first_column` is binary, I can use `astype(bool)` to get `True`/`False`
- If I take the opposite of those and `cumsum` I get a handy way of lumping together the `True`s or `1`s
- I then `groupby` and `count` with `transform`
- `transform` broadcasts the `count` aggregation across the original index
- I first use `where` to group all `0`s together.
- I use `where` again to set their counts to `0`
- I use `assign` to generate a copy of `df` with a new column.  This is because I don't want to clobber the `df` we already have.  If you want to write directly to `df` use `df['counts'] = c`

---

```
t = df.first_column.astype(bool)
c = df.groupby((~t).cumsum().where(t, -1)).transform('count').where(t, 0)
df.assign(counts=c)

    first_column  counts
0              0       0
1              0       0
2              0       0
3              1       3
4              1       3
5              1       3
6              0       0
7              0       0
8              1       2
9              1       2
10             0       0
11             0       0
12             0       0
13             0       0
14             1       5
15             1       5
16             1       5
17             1       5
18             1       5
19             0       0
20             0       0
```

Comment: I get an odd error with the above: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 62, placement implies 1`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang do you get this error with the sample data you provided?  Or other data?  If other data, edit your question and include a sample of the data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I suspect perhaps that is the problem. The original dataframe must have 62 columns perhpas? I'll look for an example to post

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with pandas groupby, which I think is quite readable. A (possible) advantage is that does not rely on the assumption that only 1 and 0 are present in the column.

The main insight is to create groups of consecutive values and then simply compute their length. We also carry the information of the value in the group, so we can filter for zeros.

```
# Relevant column -> grouper needs to be 1-Dimensional
col_vals = df['first_column']

# Group by sequence of consecutive values and value in the sequence.
grouped = df.groupby(((col_vals!=col_vals.shift(1)).cumsum(), col_vals))

# Get the length of consecutive values if they are different from zero, else zero
df['counts'] = grouped['first_column'].transform(lambda group: len(group))\
                                      .where(col_vals!=0, 0)
```

This is how the groups and keys look like:

```
for key, group in grouped:
    print key, group

(1, 0)    first_column
0             0
1             0
2             0
(2, 1)    first_column
3             1
4             1
5             1
(3, 0)    first_column
6             0
7             0
(4, 1)    first_column
8             1
9             1
(5, 0)     first_column
10             0
11             0
12             0
13             0
(6, 1)     first_column
14             1
15             1
16             1
17             1
18             1
(7, 0)     first_column
19             0
20             0
```